# Does $ \int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)| = 0$ imply $ \int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)|^2 = 0$?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

Context:I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Suppose $f, f_1, g, g_1$ all Riemann integrable complex valued functions on $[a, b]$ such that $f \sim f_1$ and $g \sim g_1$. Prove $\langle f, g \rangle = \langle f_1, g_1 \rangle$.
>
> In this problem, $f \sim f_1$ means $ \int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)| = 0$, $\langle f, g \rangle$ is the Hermitian scalar product $ \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)}$, and $\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f, f \rangle}$.

I tried saying that
\begin{align}\langle f, g \rangle &= \langle f - f_1, g \rangle + \langle f_1, g \rangle\\[0.2cm]&= \langle f - f_1, g \rangle + \overline{\langle g, f_1 \rangle}\\[0.2cm]&= \langle f - f_1, g \rangle + \overline{\langle g - g_1, f_1 \rangle} + \overline{\langle g_1, f_1 \rangle}\\[0.2cm]&= \langle f - f_1, g \rangle + \langle f_1, g - g_1 \rangle + \langle f_1, g_1 \rangle\end{align}

And I wanted to say that the first two terms were $0$ by the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality, by saying $$|\langle f - f_1, g \rangle| \leq \|f-f_1\| \cdot \|g\|$$ and that $\|f - f_1\|$ is $0$, so the left side is too. So that's why I'm wondering if there's a way to show that $$\int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)| = 0 \implies \int_a^b |f(x) - f_1(x)|^2 = 0$$

Comment: Hint: If $\int |f(x)-f_1(x)|dx=0$, then the set of $x$'s where $f(x)\not=f_1(x)$ is measure $0$.

Comment: Is that a theorem from somewhere? I mean, it makes sense, but I don't remember learning that. (Although I might've just forgotten since it's been a semester since we covered Riemann integrals.)

Comment: It's from measure theory.

Answer (score 8):

The function $|f - f_{1}|$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, hence bounded. That is, there exists a real number $M$ such that
$$
|f(x) - f_{1}(x)| \leq M,\qquad a \leq x \leq b.
$$
Consequently,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} |f(x) - f_{1}(x)|^{2}\, dx
  \leq M \int_{a}^{b} |f(x) - f_{1}(x)|\, dx = 0.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Because $|f(x)-f_1(x)|$ is non-negative, the condition $\int_a^b|f(x)-f_1(x)|dx=0$ implies that $|f(x)-f_1(x)|=0$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. Hence, $|f(x)-f_1(x)|^2=0$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$ and we get $\int_a^b|f(x)-f_1(x)|^2dx=0$.

I am using the following standard result:

> **Theorem:** Let $f:[a,b]\to[0,\infty)$ be a non-negative Riemann-integrable function. Then, $\int_a^bf(x)dx=0$ if and only if the set
>   $$\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\neq 0\}$$
>   has measure $0$.

From this result we immediately get that for a non-negative Riemann-integrable function $f:[a,b]\to[0,\infty),$
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=0\implies\int_a^bf(x)^2\,dx=0.$$

Comment: It seems OP hasn't learned measure theory, so I don't think this will help him...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD at least he/she knows what a.e. means since he already used $f\sim g$ in his question.

Comment: @Vim He used it to mean $\int|f-g|=0$ though.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD no. He means $\|f-g\|=0$ in the $\mathscr L^1$ sense. But maybe you are right about him having not learned the concept of measure, since he doesn't seem to have mentioned that it exactly means $f=g$ a.e.

Comment: (+1), but added an alternative answer for posterity.